# APC not working correctly

Tags: apc

I recently installed APC on my production server but It's not working as expected.

All my projects are handled with SVN, and on production release I have a post commit hook that runs a svn export to the correct directory.

The problem is that with APC, my website fails to display anything(white page) unless I restart apache.

I check and apc.stat is On so I dont know what is happening !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change this configuration setting:

```
apc.stat_ctime = 1
```

From [php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/apc.configuration.php#ini.apc.stat-ctime):

> Verification with ctime will avoid problems caused by programs such as svn or rsync by making sure inodes haven't changed since the last stat. APC will normally only check mtime.